# Not able to login to Kibana dashboard via ingress routing

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes-ingress, elastic-cloud

I have setup ECK by following official guide and things looks good by doing port forwarding I am able to login to kibana dashboard and view logs. But we have created ingress object for Kibana and going to Kibana via ingress URL it is not allowing to login. Any suggestions what could be wrong here?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBs5x.png)

```
apiVersion: kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Kibana
metadata:
  name: kibana-eyc-qa
spec:
  version: 8.6.0
  count: 1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: elasticsearch-eyc-qa
  config:
    server.rewriteBasePath: true
  http:
    tls:
      selfSignedCertificate:
        disabled: true
  podTemplate:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kibana
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            scheme: HTTP
            path: /eck
            port: 5601
        env:
        - name: SERVER_BASEPATH
          value: "/eck"
        - name: SERVER_PUBLICBASEURL
          value: https://kibana-qa.sbp.com:443/eck

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: elastic-qa-ingress-object-kibana
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
          more_clear_headers "Server"; 
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-http-errors: "403,502"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-modsecurity: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "150"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "150"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "150"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-next-upstream-timeout: "150"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 50m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-max-temp-file-size: 50m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /eck/$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-connections: "2000"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/modsecurity-snippet: |
      SecRequestBodyLimit 1073741824
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /eck(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: kibana-eyc-qa-kb-http
            port:
              number: 5601
```